# Как правильно прописать location`ы в Nginx?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер

Есть 2 сущности: лендинг и SPA. Необходимо чтобы переходя по адресу `http://127.0.0.1` отдавались файлы лендинга, а по любому другому (`http://127.0.0.1/sing-in` и т.п.) файлы SPA.
Застрял на следующем:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;
    index index.html;

    location = / {
        root C:\Workspace\landing;
    }

    location ~ ".+" {
        alias C:\Workspace\frontend\dist\app-frontend;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при переходе на корень (`http://127.0.0.1`) отдаются файлы SPA, т.е. первый location не срабатывает.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас там index.html. Почитайте документацию https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html

Comment: А также подумайте про то, откуда для лендинга берутся картинки, стили и скрипты

Comment: Столкнулся со схожей проблемой, подскажите удалось решить вопрос, если да, то как?